# Pairwise comparison with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, linked-data

I'd like to compare a collection of objects pairwise for a given similarity metric. The metric will be defined explicitly such that some properties much match exactly and some others can only be so different to each other (i.e., comparing floats: no more than a 50% [SMAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error) between them).

How would I go about constructing such a query? The output would ideally be an Nx2 table, where each row contains two IRIs for the comparable objects. Duplicates (i.e., 1==2 is a match as well as 2==1) are admissible but if we can avoid them that would be great as well.

I would like to run this on all pairs with a single query. I would probably be able to figure out how to do it for a given object, but when querying across all objects simultaneously this problem becomes much more difficult.

Does anyone have insights into how to perform this?

Comment: SMAPE is not symmetric...

Comment: @StanislavKralin I'm sorry? It is. It's right there in the name (and definition). It is definitely symmetric.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, l'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is this:

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/ex#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?subject1 ?subject2
WHERE {
     ?subject1 ex:belongs ex:commonCategory .
     ?subject2 ex:belongs ex:commonCategory .
     ?subject1 ex:exactProperty ?e .
     ?subject2 ex:exactProperty ?e .
     ?subject1 ex:approxProperty ?a1 .
     ?subject2 ex:approxProperty ?a2 .
     FILTER ( ?subject1 > ?subject2 ) .
     FILTER ( (abs(?a1-?a2)/(abs(?a1)+abs(?a2))) < 0.5 )
}
```

E.g., on DBpedia:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX umbel-rc: <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?subject1 ?subject2
WHERE {
    ?subject1  rdf:type        umbel-rc:Actor .
    ?subject2  rdf:type        umbel-rc:Actor .
    ?subject1  dbo:spouse      ?spouse1 .
    ?subject2  dbo:spouse      ?spouse2 .
    ?subject1  dbo:wikiPageID  ?ID1 .
    ?subject2  dbo:wikiPageID  ?ID2 .
    FILTER    ( ?subject1 > ?subject2 ) .
    FILTER    ( ?spouse1  = ?spouse2 ) .
    FILTER    ( abs(?ID1-?ID2)/xsd:float(?ID1+?ID2) < 0.05 )
}
```

Thus, probably, [Zsa Zsa Gabor](http://dbpedia.org/page/Zsa_Zsa_Gabor) and [Magda Gabor](http://dbpedia.org/page/Magda_Gabor) are the same person.
Both were spouses of [George Sanders](http://dbpedia.org/page/George_Sanders) and their `wikiPageID`'s are not very different from each other.

Some explanations:

- The `?subject1 > ?subject2` clause removes "permutation duplicates";
- On the usage of `xsd:float` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042624/sparql-arithmetic-operators-between-variables).